# Extracting continuous values and print all the lines

Tags: perl

I want to extract lines if the values are continuous for more than 4 lines (if value in col1 is same), but all lines (more than 4 should be printed) should be printed.

If a value in col1 is equal, and values in col2 and col3 are going continuously (like a continuous numbers) for more than next 4 lines, then return those lines. The value in col3 of line can be equal or can be smaller only up to 100 by col2 value of next line.

Here continuous does not mean for 1 line (that in 1 line col3 - col2). It means col3 value of line as compared to col2 value of next line.

My file is ->

```
A   0    100
A1  0    100
A1  100  200
A1  200  300
A1  400  500
A1  500  600
A1  600  700
A1  700  800
A1  1600 1700
A2  100  200
A2  200  300
A2  400  500
A2  500  600
A2  600  700
A3  800  900
```

Desired output is->

```
A1  0    100
A1  100  200
A1  200  300
A1  400  500
A1  500  600
A1  600  700
A1  700  800
A2  100  200
A2  200  300
A2  400  500
A2  500  600
A2  600  700
```

Here is 1 more example -> my input file->

```
A   0    100
A1  0    100
A1  100  200
A1  200  300
A1  500  600
A1  600  700
A1  700  800
A1  1600 1700
A2  100  200
A2  200  300
A2  400  500
A3  800  900
```

Output ->

"No lines continuous".

Now there is no output, because there should be more than 4 lines which have same col1 value and col3 value of those lines should be equal or smaller by 100, as compare to next line.

So far I tried this but is not working ->

```
use strict;
use warnings;

*ARGV or die "No input file specified";
open *first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
my @data;
while (<first>) {

     if (not @data) {
     @data = split;
     next;
     }

     my @new = split /\s+/;

     if ($new[0] eq $data[0] and $new[1] <= $data[2]+ 100) {
     $data[2] = $new[2];
          if ( $data[2] - $data[1] >= 500){
             print join("\t", @new), "\n";
          }
     }

    else {
    @data = @new;
    }
}
```

Any help please.

Comment: *"values in col2 and col3 are going continuously (like a continuous numbers)"*, what do you mean with continuous? I don't know what a continuous number is.

Comment: @Qtax : Consider 1 line (row) whose col3 is, say, 100. Then we have to see, if the col2 of next line (row), is also 100 (or at most 200). If this thing happens continuously for 5 lines, then print those 5 lines.

Comment: M42's answer should suit you then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use 5.010;

$_ = <DATA>;
chomp;
my ($p_key, $p_col1, $p_col2) = split;
my @result = ($_);
open my $fh, '>', 'path/to/output_file' or die "unable to open file:$!";
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $col1, $col2) = split;
    if ($key eq $p_key) {
        if ($col1 <= $p_col2+100) {
            push @result, $_;
        } else {
            print_to_file($fh, \@result) if (@result > 3);
            @result = ();
        }
    } else {
        print_to_file($fh, \@result) if (@result > 3);
        @result = ($_);
    }
    ($p_key, $p_col2) = ($key, $col2);
}
print_to_file($fh, \@result) if (@result > 3);

sub print_to_file {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $res = shift;
    while(@$res) {
        print $fh, $_, "\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
A   0    100
A1  0    100
A1  100  200
A1  200  300
A1  400  500
A1  500  600
A1  600  700
A1  700  800
A1  1600 1700
A2  100  200
A2  200  300
A2  400  500
A2  500  600
A2  600  700
A3  800  900
```

**output:**

```
(
  "A1  0    100",
  "A1  100  200",
  "A1  200  300",
  "A1  400  500",
  "A1  500  600",
  "A1  600  700",
  "A1  700  800",
)
(
  "A2  100  200",
  "A2  200  300",
  "A2  400  500",
  "A2  500  600",
  "A2  600  700",
)
```

Comment: I guess OP also wants to check that `$col1 >= $p_col2`, and probably `$col1 >= $col2`.

Comment: @Qtax: I'm not sure whst he really wants. But according to examples given, he wants to keep a line if $col1 not greater than $p_col2+100. i.e. `A1  200  300` and `A1  400  500` but not `A1  700  800`/ `A1  1600 1700`

Comment: @M42: Thanks. I tried your code and its working but sometimes it is not giving the last line. Also this output is coming on the screen and I am not able to store it in a file. Is there a way to store output, in a file (tab delimited) and should be in same format like our input file was. (no quotes, no brackets and no commas).

Comment: @Vikas:To store in a file, just replace all the `dump@result` by a loop that print in the output file. Could you give an example where the last line is not printed?

Comment: @M42: Sorry, that was my mistake. It is printing last line. So if I will replace all dump@result, then it means, there is no use of Data::Dump anymore?

Comment: @Vikas: Right, you can remove the line `use Data::Dump;`

Comment: @M42: I replaced the dump with loop -> while(my @result){
        print $_,"\n" if (@result > 3);
               } But it is not working now. Can you please tell what wrong am I doing?